# Getting AsyncStorage in useEffect is not setting the state before I call the fetch function

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I'm using this library:

```
const [userId, setUserId] = useState('');
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
```

When I Login here, I set the AsyncStorage:

```
    const storeUserId = async (id) => {
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(
            'userId',
            id,
            );
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }
```

As so:

```
   storeUserId(userGuid);
   navigation.navigate("Home");
```

Then when i navigate to the Home Screen, i have this in useEffect:

```
     useEffect(() => {

            AsyncStorage.getItem('userId').then(value => {
                if (value != null) {
                    setUserId(value.toString());
                    console.log("u " + value);
                    getData(0);
                }
            });

    }, []);
```

The console log outputs:

```
u 52ba85d7-5d16-4012-940d-94cddda978b2
```

Which is correct, but when getData(0); is called here:

```
 const getData = async (id) => {
    console.log("2 " + userId);
    setOnRefresh(true);
        fetch('https://soppinga.com/api/Home/GetPolls?id=' + id + "&userId=" + userId, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }})
        .then(function(response){
          return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(json){
            heartRef2.current = true;
            heartRef.current = true;
            loadData(json); setOnRefresh(false);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
        console.log('There has been a problem with your fetch operation: ' + error.message);
         // ADD THIS THROW error
          throw error;
        });
 }
```

The console log outputs empty userId, so my fetch cannot complete with the userId as empty.

So how do I get the userId in time and be able to pass it in the fetch in time?

Answer (score 1):

Nice to see you solved you problem, while it works for your case you need to be careful that it's not about "buying time" for the first effect to finish, when you set a state, the new data of the state cannot be accessed in the same render. splitting the effects solved the issue because the second effect will now fire the next time userId changes which is after the next render and it will have access to the new state in its scope

https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect

It you want to use the value of the state directly after setting it, then just use the value itself, and not the state like this:

```
useEffect(() => {

    AsyncStorage.getItem('userId').then(value => {
        if (value != null) {
            const newUserId = value.toString()
            setUserId(newUserId);
            console.log("userId " + newUserId);
            getData(newUserId) // pass it to the getData function
        }
    });

}, []);
```

Comment: I was thinking of doing the way you mentioned but the getData function is called in a few more places in the same component, that why I needed a solution to do the functionality in useEffect because like I mentioned the getData is used more than once in the same component

Answer (score 0):

I had to separate the useEffect like this:

```
useEffect(() => {

    AsyncStorage.getItem('userId').then(value => {
        if (value != null) {
            setUserId(value.toString());
            console.log("u " + value);
        }
    });

}, []);



useEffect(() => {
    if(userId.length > 0){
        getData(0);
    }
}, [userId]);
```

So when the setUserId is called, the useEffect containing the getData() will be called for enough time for the userId to be set